# Intersection of three lists with saving all intersections? (not strict intersection)

Tags: python, set, intersection

Is there the most pythonic (native) way to intersect

```py
A = {1,2,3,6,7}
B = {3,4,5,7,8}
C = {6,7,8,9,10}

# strict intersection ALL THREE sets
print(A & B & C)
```

```sh
>>> {7}
```

but how I can get ALL results that were intersected?

```sh
>>> {3,6,7,8}
```

strict

[image]

non-strict

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = {1,2,3,6,7}
B = {3,4,5,7,8}
C = {6,7,8,9,10}

print((A & B) | (B & C) | (C & A))
```

Result:

```
{3, 6, 7, 8}
```

P.S. 9 & 10 should not be part of the "non-strict" intersection

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

A = {1,2,3,6,7}
B = {3,4,5,7,8}
C = {6,7,8,9,10}

result = set()
for k,v in Counter(list(A) + list(B) + list(C)).items():
    if v > 1:
        result.add(k)

print(result)  # prints:  {3, 4, 5, 7, 8}
```

In this solution, all items are placed into a counter, and any item that was found to appear more than once is placed in the `results` set.

This should work on any number of sets (not just three).

If you prefer a one-liner instead of a loop, try this:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

A = {1,2,3,6,7}
B = {3,4,5,7,8}
C = {6,7,8,9,10}

result = {k for k,v in Counter(chain(A,B,C)).items() if v > 1}

print(result)  # prints:  {3, 4, 5, 7, 8}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is easily modifiable to handle more sets, should you decide to use more later.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is same as J-L:

```
from itertools import chain
import collections
a = list(chain.from_iterable([A,B,C]))
y = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1]
set(y)
```

---

```
{3, 6, 7, 8}
```

Comment: Nice!  But you can simplify this even further by converting the `y = [...]` line (that uses a list comprehension) to `y = {...}` (which uses a set comprehension).  That way you don't have to call `set(y)` to get it into a set, as `y` will already be a set.

Comment: but that will give unordered dict like this `{8, 7, 3,6}`